# возможно ли в параметра yandex-tank\phantom явно указать сетевой порт

Tags: яндекс-танк

Насколько мне уже пояснили в моем предыдущем вопросе - в конфигурации `yandex-tank\phantom` имеется параметр `gatling_ip`, указав который можно явно задать сетевой интерфейс, куда необходимо выдавать генерируемые запросы. А можно ли указать интерфейс по его `logical name` в системе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

указать имя интерфейса чтобы фантом выбрал доступные на нем адреса нельзя. Фантом старались сделать как можно проще =)